# Perl array in logical defined-or

Tags: arrays, perl

I was trying to assign an empty array if a given array is undefined, otherwise assign that given array. But it looks like perl array is being executed in scalar context in logical defined-or.

Example:

```
@h = 1 .. 5;
@a = @h // ();
@b = defined @h ? @h : ();

print @a; #5  
print @b; #12345
```

Is there a workaround so I can do in similar fashion like in the second line of the code?

Comment: Only scalar values can be `undef`, and it's meaningless to test an array for definedness. If you want to set `@a` to `@h` if `@h` is non-empty, otherwise set it to the empty list then you can write just `@a = @h`.

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. Thanks! @Borodin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only scalar values can be `undef`, and it's meaningless to test an array for definedness. If you want to set `@a` to `@h` if `@h` is non-empty, else set it to the empty list, then you can write just `@a = @h`.